# How to print a value from a variable in square brackets?

Tags: python, resultset, square-bracket, quotation-marks

```
last= "smith"
```

I am trying to print this line: John [Smith].

The answer is

```
last = "Smith"
msg = "John" + " ["+ last +"] "
print(msg)
```

But I don't understand why the answer is like this. Why do I need the plus signs?
Won't the quotation marks in the square brackets cause "+ last +" to become a string instead of printing out the value?
I have tried looking through my notes and am unable to understand the reasoning behind.

Comment: `"+ last +"` isn't a string.  `" ["` and `"] "` are the strings. You need to think of what quotes are matching what other quotes.

Comment: There are different ways to concat variables into a string in Python. One easier way is f-string formatting: `msg = f"John [{last}]"`.

Comment: in python using the `+` operator with strings is synonymous with "concatenate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg = "John" + " ["+ last +"] "
```

Python interprets quotes as a string delimiter - anything inside quotes is treated as a string, not as python code.

So here, `" ["` is a string, so the plus is required for string concatenation.

Comment: Ohh, I didnt't realise that the square brackets were the strings. I thought the "+ last +" were the strings and had trouble understanding the syntax. I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this.

```py
last = "Smith"
msg = "John"
msg = msg + " ["
msg = msg + last
msg = msg + "] "
print(msg)
```

If it helps, add `print(msg)` after each assignment to `msg` and see how it develops.

There are many, many, *many* other ways to do this. See [How do I put a variable inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are themselves already a string, so they don't act like normal code entities. You need the plus sign to add the strings you have created into one string.

```
first = "John"
last = "Smith"
left_b = " ["
right_b ="] "

msg = first + left_b + last + right_b
print(msg)
```

This is the same thing as what you are trying to do but everything is a variable.

It can also be written like this to avoid plus signs using string injection:

```
last = "Smith"
msg = "John {}".format(last)
```