# Not getting response through request API

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am getting proper response from API when I am passing integer value directly but I am not getting any response when I am passing integer through variable.
​

```
# Extarct information of Metadata of Design id-5071431

import requests

url = "https://www.helioscope.com/api/designs/5071431"

payload={}

headers = {

  'access_token': 'API_key',

}

​

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# <Response [200]>

des=5071431

# Extarct information of Metadata of Design id-5071431

import requests

url = "https://www.helioscope.com/api/designs/{des}"

payload={}

headers = {

  'access_token': 'API_key',

}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# <Response [500]>
```

Attached are the screenshots for the same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b91AM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf9Bx.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We ask that questions include a [mcve] with sample code as _text_ in the body of the question, not as images or links, to make it easier to know how to help.

Comment: In your case, you're passing the literal string `'{des}'` as part of your URL. You need to use an f-string or string formatting to use the variable in the string. See [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to pass number of design id using for loop. I am not getting response when I am passing integer through variable

Comment: There's no loops in this code, but that's also not the problem

Comment: Thanks G.Anderson Anderson. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

1. `response.text` will show the server response body
2. `{des}` should be replaced with an actual ID like you did in the first request

> when I am passing integer through variable.

You're not using an f-string for loading any variables into the string, so it's taken as a literal. You could also just concatenate at the end

Comment: I want to pass number of design id using for loop. I am not getting respose when I am passing integer through variable

Comment: You're getting a Response object in both cases. You'll only get a 200 status code if you use a format string correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string