# How to make bold text in python query?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm doing a GET request using the Telegram Bot API.

I use the following query

```py
telegram_msg = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/<botname>:<botAPI>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<chatID>&parseMode=MarkdownV2&photo={link}&caption=*bold\*{title}*\n\n{res}')
```

So I want the **title** to be bold. What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me please?

Comment: What is the output that you actually get?

Comment: I just get *bold\*text* around my text, looks like I don't use this code correctly

Comment: Not really sure but maybe try \\\* instead of \\*

Comment: Nope, that didn't work(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the way you pass the [parse_mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options).

---

In your url there is:

```
&parseMode=MarkdownV2
```

But that should be

```
&parse_mode=MarkdownV2
```

---

After changing that, it works as expected with the following url/code/output:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<CHAT-ID>&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&photo=http://placehold.jp/150x150.png&caption=*Foo*Bar
```

```py
import requests

chatID='my-chat-id'
link='http://placehold.jp/150x150.png'
token='my-private-token'
caption='Example text'
telegram_msg = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendPhoto?chat_id={chatID}&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&photo={link}&caption=*{caption}*')
```

---

###### Note: Make sure you're using Python 3.6 or above to use `f` strings:

[How do I put a variable’s value inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string)

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works only when I pass links, but what if I put links and text dynamically. It won't work if I pass {link} and {description}

Comment: As you currently are in your question? Are you sure you're using python3+. Consider reading [this answer that shows other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string).

Comment: Am I doing it wrong with f-String?

Comment: I've added my test-code. f Strings only work if you are using python 3.6 or higher. But the chat/id and bot token are not variables, please see my example.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Can you please help me how do I put variable with bold text into another variable?

text=*link* doesn't work. Should I use any escape character?

Comment: So you want to use a variable containing some text, to be bold?

Comment: Yes, how can I do that? I want it to contain some dynamically changing text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244052/discussion-between-laura-and-0stone0).

Comment: I've updated the code-snippet. `caption` is the non-bold variable text. Using `&caption=*{caption}*` in the url to make it bold.