# how to call curl in python with variables defined?

Tags: python

I have a python script which should execute curl command.
I used os.system.
command is:

```
os.system("curl -d 'protection=$protection&Code=$Code' -X POST https://xyz.somecompany.com/web/services/final.php")
```

and I get and error:

```
Code missingCode missingWorker with sessionID:xyz
```

I gues this is a problem with variable which is defined in python script but it can not be called in curl command? or im wrong?

variables are defined in python script as follows:

```
Code = item.decode("utf-8")
protection = (int(Code) - int(year)) / 2
```

Comment: Why use curl instead of one of pythons request libraries?

Comment: I`m not so good with python. What would be correct syntax to rewrite this command with python request libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string)

Comment: Or use `subprocess`, or `requests`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
cmd = "curl -d 'protection={protection}&Code={code}' -X POST https://xyz.somecompany.com/web/services/final.php"
os.system(cmd.format(protection=protection, code=Code))
```