# Why can't I zip a file in Python?

Tags: python

So I created a script in Python that takes a user specified file and zips it up as a zip file.

When I tried it out it doesn't work my code complains how the path is not found I have tried so many different things and looked at a lot of tutorials about how to do this none work.

This is my code:

```
import zipfile
FZ = 0
F = input("What file do you want zipped? ")
FZ = FZ + 1
with zipfile.ZipFile(("ZipFile", FZ, ".zip"), "w") as z:
    z.write(F)
input("Done! Press any key to quit... ")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" can you explain what it does and what's wrong with what it does?

Comment: what happens when you run it?  also I think this part should be a single string instead of a tuple of three strings: `("ZipFile", FZ, ".zip")`

Comment: Right, maybe you need `f"ZipFile{FZ}.zip"` instead of that tuple?

Comment: your problem is NOT zipfile module but you simply don't know how to work with strings - to create string with file name. You can't create single string using tuple `("ZipFile", FZ, ".zip")` - you have to use `f-string` like in previous comments `f"ZipFile{FZ}.zip"` or use `"ZipFile" + str(FZ) + ".zip"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are confused about how to build strings, based on this line:

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile(("ZipFile", FZ, ".zip"), "w") as z:
```

If this were a *`print`* statement, doing `print("ZipFile", FZ, ".zip")` would correctly output something like `ZipFile 1 .zip`. However that's a specific feature of how the `print` function works; in general, a tuple of strings does **not** magically get converted into just one long string. If you want to store a string, or pass one to a function, that looks like how you want, you'll have to use one of the [many existing ways to put a variable into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string). For example, as an f-string:

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile(f"ZipFile{FZ}.zip", "w") as z:
```

In that case, if `FZ` was `1`, the first argument would be passed as `"ZipFile1.zip"`