# if the counter matches to a number , return a predefined value string to use in subsequent places

Tags: python

I will be having different counter value,

if the counter value is 1, I need to use the RequestString as "FirstName=Name1,StreetName=Street1"
else if the counter value is 2, I need to use the RequestString as "FirstName=Name2,StreetName=Street2" like this I need to continue

Based on the counter value, I need to get the "RequestString" and use it in the subsequent request. Can any one help how it can be done in python ?

Comment: Are you asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the name of the variables, `Name1`, `Street1`, etc. in the request string then you can do this:

```py
def request_from_counter(value):
    return f'FirstName=Name{value},StreetName=Street{value}'
```

If you want the *values* of those variables however, then you can do this:

```py
def request_from_counter(value):
    name_value = f'Name{value}'
    street_value = f'Street{value}'
    return f'FirstName={eval(name_value)},StreetName={eval(street_value)}
```