# Iterating over folder names in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two folders, `1` and `2`. I want to go to each folder which has the file `Test.xlsx`. I tried to iterate on `file_loc` using `i in range(1,3)` but there's an error. The code works if I mention `1` or `2` on `file_loc`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for i in range(1,3):
    file_loc = "C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\i\\Test.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")
    A=df["N"].to_numpy()
    print([A])
    A = [x for x in A if str(x) != 'nan']
    print(A)
    A = [eval(e) for e in A]
    print(A)

    A=np.array(A)
    print([A])


    A_mean=[]
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        A_mean.append(np.mean(A[i]))
    print(*A_mean, sep='\n')
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept12_2022\Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1191, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1070, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 711, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\i\\Test.xlsx'
```

Comment: you need a f-string for `file_loc`, so your `i` in the string gets evaluated as number. At the moment it is just a letter in the string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string-interpolate-it-into-the-string)

Comment: Using this link, I tried ```f'{i}'``` but I get the same error. I tried to access the folder names ```1``` and ```2```, both of which has the file with the same name ```Test.xlsx```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,3):
    file_loc = f"C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\{i}\\Test.xlsx"
    ...
```

Make sure you entered correct path