# How to make a while loop change through the course of a Python game

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I’m trying to get my game to tell the player how many chances they have left after every other turn. So for example, after the first try say “WARNING: you have x amount of tries left” and then “LAST CHANCE” when the final try comes.

I’m not sure if it’s possible to loop within a loop in the way that I’m trying to do it.

```
num = 2
guess = ''
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

#make a loop to tell the player how many chances they have left

while guess != num and not(out_of_guesses):
  print("WARNING: You only get THREE chances")
  if guess_count < guess_limit :
    guess = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10: '))
    guess_count += 1
  else:
    out_of_guesses = True
    
if out_of_guesses:
  print('Out of guesses. LOSER!')
else:
  print('BINGO! The times the CHARM! WINNER!')
```

Thanks so much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHT5y.jpg)

So I want the warning to change after every other turn unless the player guesses the correct number.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/how-do-i-put-a-variable-s-value-inside-a-string-interpolate-it-into-the-string) The "variable" in question is the number of remaining guesses, which you can easily calculate from the variables you already know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to print how many guesses are left in the warning, you could do something like this:

```
print(f"WARNING: You have {guess_limit-guess_count} guesses left")
```

This uses a feature called ['f strings'](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) which allows you to put the value of a variable inside a string. Here I'm using it to put the result of `guess_limit - guess_count` inside the string, which should resolve to the number of guesses remaining.

Comment: Please look for a duplicate before answering questions. Questions involving simple language features have usually already been asked and answered

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I go about getting my code to tell the player to be careful once their last attempt comes? I want to add a completely different message. 

Thank you so much!