# How to create a "singleton" tuple with only one element

Tags: python, tuples

In the below example I would expect all the elements to be tuples, why is a tuple converted to a string when it only contains a single string?

```
>>> a = [('a'), ('b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> a
['a', 'b', ('c', 'd')]
>>> 
>>> for elem in a:
...     print type(elem)
... 
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: `('a')` just evaluates to `'a'`

Comment: Wow - 3 *correct* answers in 3 minutes :) However, note the secret of `,`: `a = 1, 2, 3; print a`

Comment: Brackets don't make a tuple, commas do.

Comment: @cdarke, except for the empty tuple `()`, which only consists in a pair of parentheses.

Comment: True, or rather, `False` - just about all an empty tuple is good for (if you see what I mean).

Comment: Just to clarify the existing answers, parentheses are used for *grouping*, so `('a')` is taken as an expression that evaluates to `'a'`. Tuples need a comma to be a tuple, except the empty tuple, which is empty parentheses, `()`.

Comment: `tuple` is an object delimited by comma not an object enclosed in parentheses. So a singleton `tuple` would be like ('a',) or tuple('a')

Comment: Should also be noted that `(True)` and `(False)` are boolean types so that evaluating `(1 == 2)` is equivalent to `1 == 2`

Answer (score 226, accepted):

> why is a tuple converted to a string when it only contains a single string?
>
> ```
> a = [('a'), ('b'), ('c', 'd')]
> ```

Because those first two elements aren't tuples; they're just strings. The parenthesis don't automatically make them tuples. You have to add a comma after the string to indicate to python that it should be a tuple.

```
>>> type( ('a') )
<type 'str'>

>>> type( ('a',) )
<type 'tuple'>
```

To fix your example code, add commas here:

```
>>> a = [('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd')]

             ^       ^
```

From the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.

If you truly hate the trailing comma syntax, a workaround is to pass a `list` to the `tuple()` function:

```
x = tuple(['a'])
```

Comment: This isn't very elegant though and looks kind of confusing. Is there any other way?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. For example: tuple("abc") (with or without extra comma) gives ('a', 'b', 'c'), while ("abc",) gives ('abc'). So tuple() seems not to be a viable option here.

Comment: @Ben Have a look at the  [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple). `tuple`  accepts an *iterable*, which a string is (iterates over characters). If you insist on not using the trailing comma, then make an intermediate list: `tuple(['abc'])`.

Comment: Sure, I am just saying that the tuple function doesn't negate the need for the comma.

Comment: Anything more explicit variant of it in python 3.x by any chance?

Comment: @matanster The language syntax has not changed in this regard. AFAIK the problem is the same for Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 26):

Your first two examples are not tuples, they are strings. Single-item tuples require a trailing comma, as in:

```
>>> a = [('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd')]
>>> a
[('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 15):

`('a')` is not a tuple, but just a string.

You need to add an extra comma at the end to make `python` take them as `tuple`: -

```
>>> a = [('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd')]
>>> a
[('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd')]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

=> If you need to convert list to tuple which have one id as a element. then this solution will help you.

```
x_list = [1]

x_tuple = tuple(x_list)
```

=> You will get this

`(1,)`

=> so now append 0 into list and then convert it into tuple

```
=> x_list.append(0)

=> x_tuple = tuple(x_list)

(1, 0)
```

Comment: ...what does this have to do with the question being asked?

Answer (score -2):

Came across this page and I was surprised why no one mentioned one of the pretty common method for tuple with one element. May be this is version thing since this is a very old post. Anyway here it is:

```
>>> b = tuple(('a'))
>>> type(b)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Strangely, this worked for me when the other answers didn't (passing a string value to a method, so i'm using a variable and not a raw string; maybe that's why `(foo,)` didn't work for me)

Comment: This won't work as intended if the input string has several characters. Try, for example, `tuple(('ab'))` and the result will be `('a', 'b')` instead of `('ab',)`.

Comment: Generally preferable way in that case is to supply a list, so as to avoid trailing comma syntax. e.g. tuple(['ab'])

Comment: This method only works for strings of length 1, nothing else.

The correct syntax is `tuple([var])`