# What is the iterator doing when it returns iterables in a for-in statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't understand why this works:

```
a = [(1,2)]
for x, y in a:
    print x, y
```

And this doesn't:

```
a = ((1,2))
for x, y in a:
    print x, y
```

I believe what happens in the first case is we create an iterator that returns a single value, (1,2). That tuple is unpacked, assigning 1 to x and 2 to y.

In the second, why doesn't the exact same thing happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do tuples with only one element get converted to strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/why-do-tuples-with-only-one-element-get-converted-to-strings)

Answer (score 8):

`a = ((1,2))` is a single `tuple` of 2 elements - the `()`s around it do nothing - it's the same as `a = (1,2)`, to create a 1-tuple, you need a trailing comma, eg: `a = ((1,2),)` which is a 1-tuple containing a 2-tuple.