# Difference between `print(9)` and `print(str(9))`

Tags: python-3.x

What is the difference between `print(9)` and `print(str(9))` in Python when the output is the same for both functions?

Comment: What's a difference between `1+4` and `2+3` when output is same for both statements?

Comment: If you were wondering why `type(9)` and `type((9))` both give the same answer (`int`) as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/why-do-tuples-with-only-one-element-get-converted-to-strings

Comment: @StefanS I think you missed the `str` part from OP’s code.

Comment: Oh yes, I did. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` will always first try to call `__str__` on the object you give it. In the first case the `__str__` of the int instance `9` is `'9'`.

In the second case, you first explicitly call `str` on `9` (which calls its `__str__` and yields `'9'`). Then, `print` calls `'9'`'s `__str__` which, if supplied with a string instance, returns it as it is resulting in `'9'` again.

So in both cases, in the end `print` will print out similar output.

Comment: Thanks@Jim these clarifies my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does

Answer (score 1):

```
print(str(9))
print(9)
```

Output:

```
9
9
```

There is no change in output. But if we check the data type by executing,

```
print(type(str(9)))
print(type(9))
```

Then we get output as,

```
<class 'str'> 
<class 'int'>
```

So, you can see, the types are different but the output is same.

Comment: No, it is an attempt to clarify the confusion! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms:

An integer is a variable that specifically holds a numerical value. Whereas a string is a variable that can hold a range of characters (including numbers).

```
print(9) says it should print the NUMERICAL value 9

print(str(9)) says it should print the character 9,
```

So if you were to do additions on both types for instance:

```
9 + 9 will always return 18

str(9) + str(9) will always return 99
```