# How to separate access in methods from BaseModelView class in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin, flask-security

I'm using **Flask-Admin** to manage my dashboard, there are few roles in my app, two of them are **superuser** and **client**.

Now, I have **User** table build by **Flask-SQLAlchemy**, and now I want to manage the table by users role. Which means the **superuser** can edit user roles in the Flask-Admin form, and in the other **client** can't do it or the form are not displayed.

Like this screenshot:
[image]
there are edit form by **superuser** role. But for now, I want the edit form not displayed if the current user has role **client**.

So, in logically I want to making something like this:

```
class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    if current_user.has_role('superuser'):
        form_excluded_columns = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
    else:
        form_excluded_columns = ('created_at', 'updated_at', 'roles')
```

Comment: It is a common problem in using Flask-Admin. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469875/6682517), it is very close to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks very much @SergeyShubin, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I following @SergeyShubin advice to following his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469875/8070090) and in that case are very similar with my case and it works perfectly.

Also @SergeyShubin answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42528619/8070090) also similar with my case. Thanks very much @SergeyShubin.