# Flask-Admin: current_user unexpectedly undefined?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a fully working Flask-Admin app that makes use of Flask-Login. In a number of places in my ModelView code, I make use of `current_user`, and this has always worked. For example, I have

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
  model.last_modified_by = current_user.get_id()
```

I'm now trying to disable editing on a field based on access level, and after I declare some `form_args`, I added:

```
if current_user.access_level == 'USER':
  form_widget_args = {'salary': {'disabled': True}}
```

This throws the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_level'`. Yet without this code, I go right into the `on_model_change` I show above, and this successfully sets the `last_modified_by` value.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a bit more digging, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337371/flask-admin-how-to-set-form-edit-rules-or-form-create-rules-based-on-role-of-u), which revealed what was going on. The value of `form_widget_args` was getting cached on app initialization, and wasn't getting checked when things were actually running (i.e. when there was a `current_user`).

I changed my code to this:

```
@property
def form_widget_args(self):
    if not has_app_context() or (current_user.access_level == 'USER'):
        form_widget_args = {'salary': {'disabled': True}}
        return form_widget_args
```

And everything is good.