# zeros() vs zeros(()) python

Tags: python-3.x, initialization

I've seen both `zeros(5)` vs `zeros((5,))` to initialize a variable in python, where `n` is an integer. When I print both variables using `print()` function, I get 
`[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]` for both options. Why would one use the second option, which seems way more complicated?

Comment: `zeros((x))`, `zeros((x, y))`, `zeros((x, y, z))`... See the pattern?

Comment: yes, thanks! But why would one use `zeros((x))` if `zeros(x)` leads to the same result? Is there a difference in dimension or the way the variable is stored? And what is the difference between `zeros((5,))` and `zeros((5))`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking `Numpy` as the example, from [`numpy.ma.zeros` doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.zeros.html#numpy.ma.zeros):

> `numpy.ma.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C') =
>   <numpy.ma.core._convert2ma instance>`
>
> Return a new array of given
>   shape and type, filled with zeros.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `shape` : *int or sequence of ints*
>
> Shape of the new array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.
>
> ...

So both `np.zeros(5)` and `np.zeros((5,))` are ok and you got the same results, but you passed with different types of parameters: the first is `int`, the second is `tuple` of `int`s, which is also valid since it is a sequence of ints. To construct a `tuple` of one `int` element, you need to add an extra comma (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element) for more information).

Then why would someone use the more complicated one? Maybe it's just their personal preferences or for the convenience that they may change the number of the dimensions later.

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer! That's a great explanation.