# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working on a web scraping project and have run into the following error.

requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?

Below is my code. I retrieve all of the links from the html table and they print out as expected. But when I try to loop through them (links) with request.get I get the error above.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import unicodedata
from pandas import DataFrame

page = requests.get("http://properties.kimcorealty.com/property/output/find/search4/view:list/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')
for ref in table.find_all('a', href=True):
    links = (ref['href'])
    print (links)
    for link in links:
        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        table = []
        # Find all the divs we need in one go.
        divs = soup.find_all('div', {'id':['units_box_1', 'units_box_2', 'units_box_3']})
        for div in divs:
            # find all the enclosing a tags.
            anchors = div.find_all('a')
            for anchor in anchors:
                # Now we have groups of 3 list items (li) tags
                lis = anchor.find_all('li')
                # we clean up the text from the group of 3 li tags and add them as a list to our table list.
                table.append([unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",lis[0].text).strip(), lis[1].text, lis[2].text.strip()])
        # We have all the data so we add it to a DataFrame.
        headers = ['Number', 'Tenant', 'Square Footage']
        df = DataFrame(table, columns=headers)
        print (df)
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations. For example It shows which line makes problem.

Comment: your mistake is double `for` loop - use print to display values in variables and you will see what silly mistake you made.

Comment: as per my understanding there isn't any error, they are just not getting what they what to be exact right?

Comment: @P.hunter The question indicates `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema`.

Comment: yea i got it thanks

Comment: btw: pandas can read tables directly from web pages - `all_tables = pandas.read_html(url)  ;  df = all_tables[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is second `for` loop in code

```
for ref in table.find_all('a', href=True):
    links = (ref['href'])
    print (links)
    for link in links:
```

`ref['href']` gives you single url but you use it as list in next `for` loop.

So you have

```
for link in ref['href']:
```

and it gives you first char from url `http://properties.kimcore...` which is `h`

Full working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import unicodedata
from pandas import DataFrame

page = requests.get("http://properties.kimcorealty.com/property/output/find/search4/view:list/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table')
for ref in table.find_all('a', href=True):
    link = ref['href']
    print(link)
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table = []
    # Find all the divs we need in one go.
    divs = soup.find_all('div', {'id':['units_box_1', 'units_box_2', 'units_box_3']})
    for div in divs:
        # find all the enclosing a tags.
        anchors = div.find_all('a')
        for anchor in anchors:
            # Now we have groups of 3 list items (li) tags
            lis = anchor.find_all('li')
            # we clean up the text from the group of 3 li tags and add them as a list to our table list.
            table.append([unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",lis[0].text).strip(), lis[1].text, lis[2].text.strip()])
    # We have all the data so we add it to a DataFrame.
    headers = ['Number', 'Tenant', 'Square Footage']
    df = DataFrame(table, columns=headers)
    print (df)
```

**BTW:** if you use comma in `(ref['href'], )` then you get tuple and then second `for` works correclty.

---

**EDIT:** it create list `table_data` at start and add all data into this list. And it convert into DataFrame at the end.

But now I see it read the same page few times - because in every row the same url is in every column. You would have to get url only from one column.

**EDIT:** now it doesn't read the same url many times

**EDIT:** now it get text and hre from first link and add to every element in list when you use `append()`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import unicodedata
from pandas import DataFrame

page = requests.get("http://properties.kimcorealty.com/property/output/find/search4/view:list/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table_data = []

# all rows in table except first ([1:]) - headers
rows = soup.select('table tr')[1:]
for row in rows: 

    # link in first column (td[0]
    #link = row.select('td')[0].find('a')
    link = row.find('a')

    link_href = link['href']
    link_text = link.text

    print('text:', link_text)
    print('href:', link_href)

    page = requests.get(link_href)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    divs = soup.find_all('div', {'id':['units_box_1', 'units_box_2', 'units_box_3']})
    for div in divs:
        anchors = div.find_all('a')
        for anchor in anchors:
            lis = anchor.find_all('li')
            item1 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", lis[0].text).strip()
            item2 = lis[1].text
            item3 = lis[2].text.strip()
            table_data.append([item1, item2, item3, link_text, link_href])

    print('table_data size:', len(table_data))            

headers = ['Number', 'Tenant', 'Square Footage', 'Link Text', 'Link Href']
df = DataFrame(table_data, columns=headers)
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes. [Parenthesis do not make a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876194/8955448).

Comment: Now I need to get all of the data frame outputs into a single df

Comment: you can create many `df` and use [merge, join, or concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to create one `df` with all data.

Comment: you can also create single `df` at start and [append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) new rows in loop.

Comment: you can also create single list at start and `append()` data to list, and at the end convert single list into single `df`

Comment: Thanks so much, this is really helping me learn. Is it also possible to add the property name to each list as a column? the property name is contained between each 'a' tag along with the first href value we scraped

Comment: yes, you can get text from `<a`> when you get `href` and later add to list when you do `append()`. See new code.