# Data type errors

Tags: python, tuples

I found strange thing about data type of integers with comma at the end of expression (see code below).

#### Code

```
a = -1,  # strange legal syntax

print('"a" has {} data type'.format(type(a)))

if type(a) == tuple:

    print(len(a))

else:

    print('It is not a tuple!')

print('If we print "-1," directly, without variable, then ... {}'.format(type(-1,)))
```

#### Questions:

Using Jupyter notebook & Spyder console I find different results.
What is going on with this? What data type does the variable "a" has: int or tuple?

Comment: where are you getting the "not a tuple" result? `a` would be tuple in both python2 and python3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a tuple with only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element).

Comment: `a` will **always** be a tuple, in *every* version of Python, regardless of whether or not you use a Jupyter notebook (or some other IDE)

Answer (score 2):

`a` (defined as `a = 1,` is a `tuple`, period - it's the comma that defines a literal tuple, not the parens (except for the empty tuple of course). But the expression `type(-1,)` yields `int` because the comma is parsed as being part of the function call syntax rule, which takes precedence over the literal tuple syntax rule. Adding parens around the `type()` argument - ie `type((-1,))` will force the parser to first eval what's inside the inner parens - hence creating a tuple instead.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
a = -1,
```

is equal to this

```
a = (-1,)
```

It is a tuple.