# How to get element from iterator object?

Tags: python-3.x

can anyone try to explain to me how the following code work? As I understand, unpack is like `a, b, i = [1,2,3]` but how the following code work to get x? I have try to debug if I have `x = iter(collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5], maxlen=1))`
 <_collections._deque_iterator object at 0x01239>

```
import collections
x, = iter(collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5], maxlen=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler example

```
>>> x = [24]
>>> x
[24]
>>> x, = [24]
>>> x
24

>>> x, y = [24, 96]
>>> x
24
>>> y
96
```

It's equivalent to your example since if you do `list(iter(collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5], maxlen=1)))` it's just a list with one element, `[5]`.

You're correct that this is doing unpacking. You could write it as `(x,)` so that it looks more like a tuple if just `x,` is confusing. The comma after x makes `x` refer to the [first element of a tuple with one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element).

Answer (score 0):

Your code above produces x=5 for me, not an iterator object.

Usually with an iterator object, (like a generator) use of the `next()` works

Here's a short example with the fibonacci sequence. Using the `yield` produces a generator object.

```
def iterative_fib(n):
    a,b = 0,1
    i=1
    while i<n:
        a, b = b, a+b
#         print(b)
        i+=1
    yield b

x = iterative_fib(50)
next(x)  # 12586269025
```

I'm not 100% sure specifically in your case, but try using `next` because `next` expects an iterator. If this doesn't work, then maybe produce a code example that replicates your issue.

Docs for `next()` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Edit:
Seeing some other answers regarding unpacking lists, here are some other ways using `*`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a,b,c,d,e = [1,2,3,4,5] # you already mentioned this one
a, *b = [1,2,3,4,5]  # a =[1], b=[2, 3, 4, 5]
a, *b, c, d = [1,2,3,4,5]  #a =[1], b=[2,3], c=[4], d=[5]
*a, b, c = [1,2,3,4,5] # a=[1,2,3], b=[4], c=[5]
#But this wont work:
a, *b, *c = [1,2,3,4,5]  # SyntaxError: two starred expressions in assignment
```