# How to separate each elements of a nested list and convert the list to the list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a nested list like below:

```
Zeros = [[1], [2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

How can I separate each element and make a list of tuples, like below:

```
Modified_zeros = [(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try iterating each element in the nested list and finally adding the single element in brackets with `,`. There are [other similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element) to create tuples.

```
results = [(j,) for i in Zeros for j in i]
```

Output:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, How can I get rid of the comma after the numbers?

Comment: If you do not have comma then, it is no longer tuples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element

Answer (score 1):

Based off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists):

```py
flat_list = [(item,) for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Where `l` is your original list (Zeros in your case)

Answer (score 0):

for nested list at multiple level

```
Zeros = [[1], [2], [3, 4], [5, 6,[1,2,3,4]]]

def fun(l):
    res=[]
    if isinstance(l,list):
        for i in l:
            res.extend(fun(i))
    elif isinstance(l,int):
        res.append((l,))
    return res

print(fun(Zeros))
```

output

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
```