# what is "print(not())" in Python?

Tags: python, printing

How does `print(not("0"))` gives a `false` as output and `print(not())` gives a `True` as output?
what does the statement do?

```
print(not("0"))
print(not())
```

Comment: `not()` -> `not ()` where `()` is the empty tuple, since empty tuples are falsey, then not falsey is `True`. In the case of `not("0")` -> `not "0"`, since `"0"` is truthy, not truthy is `False`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: Fundamentally, you seem to think that the `not` keyword is a function, which is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, empty sequences such as `()`, `[]`, `''` and `{}` all evaluate to False, as well as the interger `0`. You can check this by using the bool() function on any of these values.

In your first print, the `not` operator returns the boolean value that is the opposite of the boolean value of `("0")`, which isn't an empty sequence nor `0`. In other words, if you call `bool(("0"))`, you will get `True` in return, and `not True` returns `False`.

In your second print, it's exactly the opposite happening. `bool(())` is `False`, therefore `not ()` should be `True`.

---

BTW: In your first print example, the value `("0")` is [**not** a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element), but a string. I mention this just in case you were thinking otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Not is very similar to the if condition !=. If a value is truthy, then it returns false. If a value is falsy, it returns true. Since most strings are truthy, it returns false, and since a None value is falsy, it returns true
so for example `print(not(True))` would return false and `print(not(False))` would return true

Comment: "since a null value is falsy" There are not null values. Python has a `None` object, but that isn't coming into play here

Comment: Sorry, I'm a js developer

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: No, `None` isn't involved here at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you pass 0 as a string to the not function, it considers it as a True value and thus negating it becomes False. Whereas an empty string is considered as False value and thus negating it becomes True. If you pass 0 as a number instead of a string, it will return you True again.