# Python Threading - Crash with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I wrote a small python script using Python's threading module for multi-threading.
The target function that gets called by `threading.Thread` takes 2 arguments (`self` and another value). But I always get the following error `TypeError: example() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`
even if only 2 arguments are given.

```py
import threading
import random
num=random.randint(1,999)

threadN=10 #number of processes
a="11" #testing value
class ExampleClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num=num

    def example(self,a):
        print(self.num)
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl=ExampleClass()
    while threadN>0:

        threading.Thread(target=cl.example, args=(a)).start()
        threadN-=1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this code incomplete?

Comment: No, but by looking at the docs again I found my issue....

Comment: You should at it as an answer.

Comment: `args` has to be list or tuple but `()` doesn't  create tuple. You have to add comma - `args=(a,)`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12876177/1358308 for why `(a)` isn't doing what you think it's doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`args` has to be list or tuple but `()` doesn't create tuple. You have to use comma to create tuple with single value - `args=(a,)`

```
 threading.Thread(target=cl.example, args=(t,)).start()
```

---

`()` is here only to separate comma which creates tuple from comma which separate arguments in function. You could do the same without `()`but you would have to create tuple before thread

```
 arguments = a,
 threading.Thread(target=cl.example, args=arguments).start()
```

Comment: interesting! thanks for pointing this out! didn't know tuple was needed, thought either list or just a string. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, just found my issue, looked again in the docs and found out following thing:

`threading.Thread(target=cl.example args=[t]).start()`
Using [ ] for the arguments solves the problem...

Comment: cant mark it yet, as its my own answer and that means I cannot accept it as answer in less than 2 days. But will do once I can!