# Why is there a comma after the variable in this sqlite query?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-delete

I have the following code and it works, but I need to understand why there is a comma after the variable id_to_remove, can someone explain to me why that has to be there? (I bolded the part I don't understand)

```
def delete_user(id_to_remove):
    sql = "DELETE FROM USERS WHERE ID = ?"
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    **cursor.execute(sql, (id_to_remove, ))**
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

So I don't know why its id_to_remove,  and not just cursor.execute(sql,(id_to_remove))

Comment: `(id_to_remove, )` is a tuple containing one item, `id_to_remove`.

Comment: That is because execute expects as second parameter an iterable (a list) and if you do not put the comma there  (id_to_remove) just between parentheses will transformed into an int.

Comment: Check [One Element Tuples](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax), and/or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element)

Comment: Thank you so much, got some reading to do. :0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it will replace all the `?` values with the ones in the `tuple`. If you don't put a comma then it is a single value, you need to add it to construct a single value `tuple`.