# Python list extend getting TypeError

Tags: python, list

I've been using Python for some time (weeks). The other day I ran into this weird error and couldn't figure out why. Any idea ?

```py
>>> t1 = [1, 2]
>>> t2 = (3, 4)
>>> t1.extend(t2)
>>> t1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> t3 = (5)
>>> t1.extend(t3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try: `t3 = (5,)` and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element

Comment: Thanks, this link helped a lot. But I'm still wondering why `(5)` should be interpreted as `5`. Why this design ?

Comment: Parentheses are used to define operator precedence in expressions, so Python evaluates the expression `(5)` as the integer 5. To distinguish this from a single element tuple, Python had to use some other syntax to avoid ambiguity, and it chose the trailing comma like so: `(5,)`. Tuples are great, but this is ugly and regrettable, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah this is kinda ugly. Nonetheless, now I understand it much better. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Interestingly, the following are also valid: `t1 = 5,` and `t2 = tuple([5])`. The latter at least makes your intention very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message says, `t3` is not a tuple or a list, it's just an integer.

In order to initialize a tuple with a single item, add a comma behind:

```py
>>> type((5))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((5,))
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You are typing to create `tuple` with a single element but you have instead created an `int` object in python. The exception that you have got clearly says that.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876194/5735010) link.

```
t3 = (5) # This creates an int object with value 5 in Python
t3 = (5,) # Right way to create a tuple with single element.
```

The parentheses don't automatically make them tuples. You have to add a comma after the int to indicate to python that it should be a tuple.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences),

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.