# Asynchronous multiprocessing in Python with pool apply_async

Tags: python, parallel-processing, networkx, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I would like to process a temporal graph (essentially, a list of [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) graphs) in parallel using asynchronous parallelism on a shared memory machine. To achieve it I use `Pool.apply_async()` from the `multiprocessing` module. The temporal graph consists of 5 unit (snapshot) graphs. For each unit graph I perform multiple computationally expensive matrix operations.

Consider a simple sequential example first:

```
#------------------------------------
# Constants
#------------------------------------
NV  = 100    # No. of vertices
NE  =  25    # No. of edges
NG  =   5    # No. of unit graphs

#------------------------------------
# Generate random time-varying graph
#------------------------------------
Gt = gen_time_graph(NV, NE, NG)

# Snapshot index
k = 0

# for each unit graph
for Gk in Gt:

    # Temporal adjacency matrix
    Atk = adj_mtrx(Gk)

    # Temporal weight matrix
    # ...

    # Temporal eigenvector centrality
    # ...

    k += 1
```

It works flawlessly. Next, I attempt to assign each matrix operation to a worker from a pool:

```
#------------------------------------
# Constants
#------------------------------------
NV  = 100    # No. of vertices
NE  =  25    # No. of edges
NG  =   5    # No. of unit graphs
NP  =   2    # No. of processes

#------------------------------------
# Generate random time-varying graph
#------------------------------------
Gt = gen_time_graph(NV, NE, NG)

# Snapshot index
k = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes=NP) as pool:

        # for each unit graph
        for Gk in Gt:
    
            # Temporal adjacency matrix
            Atk = pool.apply_async( adj_mtrx, (Gk) ).get()
    
            # Temporal weight matrix
            # ...

            # Temporal eigenvector centrality
            # ...

            k += 1
```

However, here the code crashes with the following error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
TypeError: adj_mtrx() takes 1 positional argument but 100 were given
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./aggr_vs_time_dat_par_mini.py", line 100, in <module>
    Atk = pool.apply_async( adj_mtrx, (Gk) ).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: adj_mtrx() takes 1 positional argument but 100 were given
```

I need help debugging the problem. It seems, the graph `Gk` is decomposed by the `Pool` and is passed to the function as a set of vertices. Also I would be grateful, if you could comment on (the appropriatness of) my general parallelisation approach with `Pool.apply_async()` from `multiprocessing`.

You may find all the necessary code for the minimal working example below:

```
import networkx as nx
import random   as rnd
import numpy    as np

from multiprocessing import Pool

# Generates random graph
def gen_rnd_graph(nv, ne):
    
    # Create random list of sources
    Vsrc = [rnd.randint(0,nv-1) for iter in range(ne)]
    
    # Create random list of sinks
    Vsnk = [rnd.randint(0,nv-1) for iter in range(ne)]
    
    # Create random list of edge weights
    U = [rnd.random() for iter in range(ne)]
    
    # Create list of tuples {Vsrc, Vsnk, U}
    T = list(zip(Vsrc,Vsnk,U))
    
    # Create graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    # Create list of vertices
    V = list(range(nv))
    
    # Add nodes to graph
    G.add_nodes_from(V)
    
    # Add edges between random vertices with random edge weights
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(T)
    
    return G

# Generates time-varying graph
def gen_time_graph(nv, ne, ng):

    # Initialise list of graphs
    l = []

    for i in range(ng):
        gi = gen_rnd_graph(nv, ne)
        l.append(gi)

    return l

# Computes adjacency matrix for snaphot of time-varying graph
def adj_mtrx(Gk):

    # no. of vertices
    n = Gk.number_of_nodes()

    # adjacency matrix
    Ak = np.zeros([n,n])

    # for each vertex
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if Gk.has_edge(i,j): Ak[i,j] = 1
        
    return Ak

#------------------------------------
# Constants
#------------------------------------
NV  = 100    # No. of vertices
NE  =  25    # No. of edges
NG  =   5    # No. of unit graphs
NP  =   2    # No. of processes

#------------------------------------
# Generate random time-varying graph
#------------------------------------
Gt = gen_time_graph(NV, NE, NG)

# Snapshot index
k = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes=NP) as pool:

        # for each unit graph
        for Gk in Gt:
        
            # Temporal adjacency matrix
            Atk = pool.apply_async( adj_mtrx, (Gk) ).get()
        
            k += 1
```

Comment: I guess its only a minor typo. Can you try replacing `(Gk)` with `(Gk,)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) the signature of the function is

```
apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback[, error_callback]]]])
```

Consequently, you need to pass `Gk` as a tuple, i.e. `(Gk,)`:

```
Atk = pool.apply_async( adj_mtrx, (Gk,) ).get()
```

### Background

Your function retrieves `*Gk` as input, which results in the list of nodes:

```
import networks as nx
g = nx.karate_club_graph()
print(*g)
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
```

#### 1 and 0 length tuples

More details about creating 0 and 1 element tuples: [How to create a tuple with only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element) or directly the section in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Basically, you create with `()` an tuple of length `0`, with `(Gk,)` a tuple of length 1, and for any larger number of elements you can either use `(x_1, ..., x_n)` or `(x_1, ..., x_n,)`.

#### `*`-operator

The `*`-operator can be used to use an arbitrary amount of arguments. See [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and [section before](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). Similarly, you can use `**` for arbitrary amount of keyword arguments. For more details, take a look at [What does the star operator mean, in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call) and the duplicates listed within this question.

Comment: It works! Would you please expand your answer on the `(Gk,)` "comma" notation? What shall I pass, when there are two arguments, for example? `(Gk, Gl, )` or `(Gk, Gl)`? Also it is hard to notice from the `apply_async()` function signature, that the input parameters should be a tuple. If possible, would you also tell a few words about the `*g`? What is it?

Comment: I've added some references for the single element tuple and the `*`-operator