# MySQL ProgrammingError on simple SELECT query with user-provided input

Tags: python, mysql

```
def search():
    searc = input("Enter the name you want to search: ")
    s = (searc)
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM studen WHERE Name = {}".format(s))
    for i in mycursor:
        print(i)
```

I'm trying to fetch data from the `studen` table where name is entered by the user.

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> ERROR: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ayush' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that your query is missing quotes. The string you get with `.format()` looks like this, assuming `ayush` is your input:

```sql
SELECT * FROM studen WHERE Name = ayush
```

But it needs to look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM studen WHERE Name = 'ayush'
```

However, you shouldn't be using `.format()` at all since it leaves you wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

[This is the proper way to parametrize a query using `mysql.connector`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html):

```py
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM studen WHERE Name = %s", (s,))
```

Note also that I have used `(s,)` instead of `(s)` here [to get a tuple of one element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12876177/354577).

Comment: Yes  it works. I actually tried your code a day ago but instead of writing this (s ,) I wrote (s) without comma. Thank you for helping out.