# python oracle excute error(ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number)

Tags: python, oracle, bind-variables

hi i am korean so not native english speaker

anyway i have question

when i learning sql and python flask connect

this is my code

```
  sql='''select count(*) from member where id = :1 '''
    result=curs.execute(sql,(join_id))
    cnt=result.fetchone()
```

this code print (ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number) error message

ok i solved error

```
 sql='''select count(*) from member where id = :1 '''
    result=curs.execute(sql,(join_id,)
    cnt=result.fetchone()
```

like this( join_id (add),)

that is my question

why different result (,) or not

i think it just one binding variable
so why need (,)??

Comment: `(join_id)` is not a tuple it is just parenthesis around your variable and can be simplified to `join_id`. `(join_id,)` is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Because the binding variables always need to be in a tuple, even if it's a 1-tuple. (This stands for all Python SQL libraries that adhere [to the DB-API spec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0248/#cursor-objects).)

Since in Python `(foo)` is just a parenthesized `foo`, to build an 1-tuple, you'll need the trailing comma (see e.g. [How to create a tuple with only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element)).