# Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" trying to check for an even/odd number?

Tags: python, string, format

This code gives an error

```
print('type a whole number:')
n = input()
if n % 2 == 1:
    print('Odd');
else:
    print('Even');
```

I'm assuming there's something special I have to do to variable n in the if statement? I am a beginner to Python.

Comment: Python 2.x or Python 3.x ???

Comment: @Schoolboy It's surely py3.x, as `input()` returns an integer in py2.x, and the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting` clearly suggest that `input()` is returning a string here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to fix it:

```
n = int(input("type a whole number:"))
```

Since [input()](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) returns a string, you need to convert it to an int first, using [int()](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: In Python 2.7 `>>> type(input("type a whole number:"))
type a whole number:23
<type 'int'>` But `>>> type(raw_input("type a whole number:"))
type a whole number:23
<type 'str'>`

Comment: Because like @Ashwini said, In Py 3.x input() returns a string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `n` to an integer first, in py 3.x [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) returns a string.:

```
n = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the user input `n` to an integer first.
i.e. Simply Change :

```
n = input()
```

To :

```
n = int(input())
```

Also, `input()` can take a string as an argument, which is printed before taking the input.
So, you can change

```
print('type a whole number:')
n = int(input())
```

To

```
n = int(input('type a whole number:'))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The user's input is **a string, not an integer, regardless of what was typed**. It must be converted to integer first, like so:

```
# not this:
# n = input()
# but this:
n = int(input())
```

See [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427) for details.

### Why this error message?

Python allows a string on the left-hand side of `%`. However, this has a **[completely different meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452)**: the string will be treated as a "template" into which other strings can be substituted. The template string should have one or more "placeholders", which start with a `%`. There are many possible variations, but the simplest examples look like:

```
>>> '%s' % 1
'1'
>>> '%s and %s' % (1, 2)
'1 and 2'
```

(Notice that the first syntax does not use a tuple; if there is only one value to substitute and that value is a tuple, [it should be wrapped in its own "singleton" tuple first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602).)

[Because the user's input does not happen to contain any valid placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500), the attempt to evaluate `n % 2` will therefore try to substitute one value into a supposed "template string" that doesn't have anywhere to put it. Python reports this as a `TypeError`. Arguably it should be a `ValueError` instead (since the problem is that the template string doesn't contain the appropriate number of placeholders), but calling it a `TypeError` accidentally points at the real cause: `n` should have been an integer instead.