# How can I read inputs as numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input, int

Why are `x` and `y` strings instead of ints in the below code?

(Note: in Python 2.x use `raw_input()`. In Python 3.x use `input()`. `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3.x)

```
play = True

while play:

    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    y = input("Enter a number: ")

    print(x + y)
    print(x - y)
    print(x * y)
    print(x / y)
    print(x % y)

    if input("Play again? ") == "no":
        play = False
```

Comment: [asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Since Python 3, `input` returns a string which you have to explicitly convert to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), like this

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

You can accept numbers of any base like this

```
>>> data = int(input("Enter a number: "), 8)
Enter a number: 777
>>> data
511
>>> data = int(input("Enter a number: "), 16)
Enter a number: FFFF
>>> data
65535
>>> data = int(input("Enter a number: "), 2)
Enter a number: 10101010101
>>> data
1365
```

The second parameter tells it the base of the number and then internally it understands and converts it. If the entered data is wrong it will throw a `ValueError`.

```
>>> data = int(input("Enter a number: "), 2)
Enter a number: 1234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '1234'
```

For values that can have a fractional component, the type would be `float` rather than `int`:

```
x = float(input("Enter a number:"))
```

#### Differences between Python 2 and 3

**Summary**

- Python 2's `input` function evaluated the received data, converting it to an integer implicitly (read the next section to understand the implication), but Python 3's `input` function does not do that anymore.
- Python 2's equivalent of Python 3's `input` is the `raw_input` function.

**Python 2.x**

There were two functions to get user input, called [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) and [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). The difference between them is, `raw_input` doesn't evaluate the data and returns as it is, in string form. But, `input` will evaluate whatever you entered and the result of evaluation will be returned. For example,

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
>>> data = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: 5 + 17
>>> data, type(data)
(22, <type 'int'>)
```

The data `5 + 17` is evaluated and the result is `22`. When it evaluates the expression `5 + 17`, it detects that you are adding two numbers and so the result will also be of the same `int` type. So, the type conversion is done for free, and `22` is returned as the result of the `input` and stored in the `data` variable. You can think of `input` as the `raw_input` composed with an [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) call.

```
>>> data = eval(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
Enter a number: 5 + 17
>>> data, type(data)
(22, <type 'int'>)
```

**Note:** You should be careful when you are using `input` in Python 2.x. I explained why one should be careful when using it, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122817/1903116).

But, `raw_input` doesn't evaluate the input and returns as it is, as a string.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
>>> data = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: 5 + 17
>>> data, type(data)
('5 + 17', <type 'str'>)
```

**Python 3.x**

Python 3.x's [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and Python 2.x's `raw_input` are similar and `raw_input` is not available in Python 3.x.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
>>> data = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: 5 + 17
>>> data, type(data)
('5 + 17', <class 'str'>)
```

Comment: Is there any other way, like a function or something so that we dont need to convert to int in 3.x other than doing explicit conversion to int??

Comment: @ShreyanMehta `eval` would work, but don't go for that unless you have pressing reasons.

Comment: @thefourtheye at least use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for that. It does not have the security concerns of `eval`.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the other comments here. Calling a function would take the same amount of work as calling `int`. If you mean, something that combines the `int` conversion work with the `input` getting work, it's easy to create that yourself.

Answer (score 53):

In Python 3.x, `raw_input` was renamed to `input` and the Python 2.x `input` was removed.

This means that, just like `raw_input`, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python 3.x always returns a string object.

To fix the problem, you need to explicitly make those inputs into integers by putting them in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 35):

For multiple integer in a single line, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) might be better.

```
arr = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

If the number is already known, (like 2 integers), you can use

```
num1, num2 = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 19):

`input()` (Python 3) and `raw_input()` (Python 2) *always* return strings. Convert the result to integer explicitly with `int()`.

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 13):

Multiple questions require multiple integers to be entered on a single line. The best way is to enter the entire string of numbers line by line and split them into integers. Here is the Python 3 version:

```
a = []
p = input()
p = p.split()      
for i in p:
    a.append(int(i))
```

You can also use list comprehensions:

```
p = input().split("whatever the seperator is")
```

To convert all input from string to int we do the following:

```
x = [int(i) for i in p]
print(x, end=' ')
```

List elements should be printed in straight lines.

Answer (score 7):

Convert to integers:

```
my_number = int(input("enter the number"))
```

Similarly for floating point numbers:

```
my_decimalnumber = float(input("enter the number"))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    n=input()
    n=int(n)
    arr1=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

the for loop shall run 'n' number of times . the second 'n' is the length of the array.
the last statement maps the integers to a list and takes input in space separated form .
you can also return the array at the end of for loop.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a problem of taking integer input while solving a problem on [CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TLG), where two integers - separated by space - should be read from one line.

While `int(input())` is sufficient for a single integer, I did not find a direct way to input two integers.  I tried this:

```py
num = input()
num1 = 0
num2 = 0

for i in range(len(num)):
    if num[i] == ' ':
        break

num1 = int(num[:i])
num2 = int(num[i+1:])
```

Now I use `num1` and `num2` as integers.

Comment: This looks very interesting.  However, isn't `i` destroyed when the `for` loop is exited?

Comment: `@hosch250` When a loop is exited, the value of the index variable (here, `i`) remains.  I tried this piece out, and it works correctly.

Comment: For this kind of input manipulation, you can either `num1, num2 = map(int, input().split())` if you know how much integers you will encounter or `nums = list(map(int, input().split()))` if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
def dbz():
    try:
        r = raw_input("Enter number:")
        if r.isdigit():
            i = int(raw_input("Enter divident:"))
            d = int(r)/i
            print "O/p is -:",d
        else:
            print "Not a number"
    except Exception ,e:
        print "Program halted incorrect data entered",type(e)
dbz()

Or 

num = input("Enter Number:")#"input" will accept only numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

While in your example, `int(input(...))` does the trick in any case, `python-future`'s [`builtins.input`](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#input) is worth consideration since that makes sure your code works for both Python 2 and 3 *and* disables Python2's default behaviour of `input` trying to be "clever" about the input data type (`builtins.input` basically just behaves like `raw_input`).