# python tuple print issue

Tags: python, tuples, string-formatting

```
print '%d:%02d' % divmod(10,20)
```

results in what I want:

```
0:10
```

However

```
print '%s %d:%02d' % ('hi', divmod(10,20))
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    print '%s %d:%02d' % ('hi', divmod(10,20))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple
```

How do I fix the second print statement so that it works?

I thought there was a simpler solution than

```
m = divmod(10,20)
print m[0], m[1]
```

or using python 3 or format().

I feel I'm missing something obvious

Comment: from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602/printing-tuple-with-string-formatting-in-python

print "this is a tuple: %s" % (divmod(10,20),)

Comment: I think was a good question.  Nothing obvious about it!  Pretty subtle, in my opinion.  Very informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *nesting* tuples; concatenate instead:

```
print '%s %d:%02d' % (('hi',) + divmod(10,20))
```

Now you create a tuple of 3 elements and the string formatting works.

Demo:

```
>>> print '%s %d:%02d' % (('hi',) + divmod(10,20))
hi 0:10
```

and to illustrate the difference:

```
>>> ('hi', divmod(10,20))
('hi', (0, 10))
>>> (('hi',) + divmod(10,20))
('hi', 0, 10)
```

Alternatively, use `str.format()`:

```
>>> print '{0} {1[0]:d}:{1[1]:02d}'.format('hi', divmod(10, 20))
hi 0:10
```

Here we interpolate the first argument (`{0}`), then the first element of the second argument (`{1[0]}`, formatting the value as an integer), then the second element of the second argument (`{1[1]}`, formatting the value as an integer with 2 digits and leading zeros).

Comment: +1 Because `.format` is SO MUCH BETTER than the old `%` method, if for no other reason than your example right here.

Comment: ((('hi',) + divmod(10,20))) also works.  So tuples must unwrap themselves or something....

Answer (score 1):

```
print '%s %d:%02d' % ('hi',divmod(10,20)[0], divmod(10,20)[1])
                       ^         ^                 ^
                       1         2                 3
```

Parentheses with commas indicate tuples, parens with concatenation (+) will return strings.

You need a 3-tuple for 3 inputs as shown

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're faster than me, hold on

Comment: You were a little too fast to post and not try first. :-)

Comment: `'hi' + divmod(10,20)` -> `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects`

Comment: @RussW I know, What i said doesn't contradict that

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but i couldn't think of another one that didn't copy yours.  Otherwise i would have posted what you did, at least it works, its just not accept-worthy

Comment: @Stephan I like that you fixed it though

Comment: +1 for getting something that worked.  I had to punt my answer and retreat in shame....  :)

Comment: @Jim giving up is the smart thing to do when MP posts an answer, but I STRIDE FORTH with a UNIQUE and much less optimal answer!

Comment: Other answers can help to understand the problem better.  I still am puzzled that ((('hi',) + divmod(10,20))) also works.

Comment: @Jim he is concatenating 2 tuples, one of em says 'hi' the other one is a pair

Comment: Yes, but both (('hi',) + divmod(10,20)) AND ((('hi',) + divmod(10,20))) work.  I'm definitely at the shallow end of the pool when it comes to python tuples....

Comment: You are just grouping statements now; *just* a pair if parenthesis does not make a tuple. It is the *comma* that makes a tuple, actually. Parenthesis just make things unambiguous for the parser. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string and a tuple to the format's tuple, not a string and two ints. This works:

```
print '%s %d:%02d' % (('hi',) + divmod(10,20))
```

There is a tuple concatenation.