# How do I subtract vector tuples?

Tags: tuples, python-3.4

**I was asked to Perform the subtraction one coordinate at a time by subscripting in the original tuples.**

I'm trying to subtract two tuples and print out the final answer using the string format (%s). I tried using numpy, but it was giving me an error while trying to print. This is what I tried.

```
`import numpy'

AA = (2.3, 4.5)
BB = (-2.0, -5.0)
ptbminusa = tuple(numpy.subtract((3.5, 1.2),(-2.7, -3.2)))
print("ptB - ptA = %s" %ptbminusa )
```

But, every time I run the file I get.

```
print("ptB - ptA = %s" %ptbminusa )`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print a tuple so you must use the following line:

```
print("ptB - ptA = %s" % (ptbminusa,) )
```

See Alex Martelli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455623/3223917) for more information.