# can't figure out why two values "look" the same but aren't equal

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, pycharm

I am writing an application on PyCharm in Python 2.6.6 and not getting the output I expect:

```
if VAR1 != row2:
    print "Status 1: %s" %VAR1
    print "Status 2: %s" %row2
    print "%s != %s" % (VAR1, row2)
```

Output:

```
Status 1: 3
Status 2: 3
3 != (3L,)
```

Does somebody know what's happening here?

Comment: what are VAR1 and row2?

Comment: What's strange about it?

Comment: @EzerK they are two different variable witch i catch from select command.

Comment: @IronFist in Status 2 row2 is 3 and the last line row2 is (3L,).

Comment: try to be more specific, that is the source of your strange output, check for yourself with other random vars

Comment: @user5734100 `VAR1` is an `INTEGER` and `row2` is a SQL list (returned as a Python tuple) that was returned from a query which has only one element.

Comment: @PM2Ring It's a python tuple, but a SQL list. Edited my comment.

Comment: @erip: Ah, rightio. I didn't see any mention of SQL by the OP, but I guess "select command" is a clue. :)

Comment: I think this has the guts of a good question, but it's not being asked the right way.

Comment: FWIW, this potentially confusing behaviour is one of the reasons that `%`-style formatting is now discouraged and modern Python practice favours the use of `.format`, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602/printing-tuple-with-string-formatting-in-python (but I still like the old style :) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row2` is a tuple with 1 element.
the `%` formatting of a string can be used with a single value or a tuple of one or more values.

In `print "Status 2: %s" %row2` the tuple is unpacked and the sole element is used. In `print "%s != %s" % (VAR1, row2)` you have packed the tuple `row2` in another tuple, so the second `%s` displays the representation of this tuple, e.g. `(3,)`.

Comment: Thanks.
I did this and every things ok.