# Pylint raise logging-format-interpolation on line with fstring

Tags: pylint, f-string

I can not understand what is wrong in this line, could you explain it for me :)?

Code:

```
log.debug(F"Create Error with receive_date={self.receive_date} data={data}")
```

Pylint:

```
ErrorService/Error.py:24:8: W1202: Use % formatting in logging functions and pass the % parameters as arguments (logging-format-interpolation)
```

Comment: See, if this thread on pylint and logging format interpolation is useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619790/pylint-message-logging-format-interpolation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyLint message: logging-format-interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619790/pylint-message-logging-format-interpolation)