# Python pylint(raising-format-tuple) Exception arguments suggest string formatting might be intended

Tags: python, exception, pylint

With a simple custom exception class defined as:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass
```

And this call:

```
foo = 'Some more info'
raise MyError("%s: there was an error", foo)
```

`pylint` gives:

> Exception arguments suggest string formatting might be intended `pylint(raising-format-tuple)`

What does this message mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Any one of these fixes the message, depending on your version of Python.

```
foo = 'Some more info'
raise MyError("%s: there was an error" % foo )
raise MyError("{}: there was an error".format(foo))
raise MyError(f"{foo}: there was an error")
```

The message is triggered when `pylint` sees the `%s` tag in the string with no following arguments. Instead of raising an exception with the string `"Some more info: there was an error"` you'll get an exception with a tuple, where the first element is `": there was an error"` and the second is the contents of `foo`. This is likely not the intended effect.

In the code I was using, there was extensive use of `logging`, and I suspect the original author confused the exception raising with [lazy logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619790/pylint-message-logging-format-interpolation).

Comment: Your comment "_I suspect the original author confused the exception raising with lazy logging_."  exactly nailed it !!

Comment: Took me a while to understand - indeed I was trying to perform lazy logging :D. Thanks!