# Pylint Message: Log - formatting - Error (Tried much)

Tags: python, logging, parameters, format, pylint

I want to pylint `app.py` which is in the following github repository :

`https://github.com/rajas2716/Udacity_MachineLearning_Project.git`

But it gives the following messages

```
app.py:16:4: W1202: Use % formatting in logging functions and pass the % parameters as arguments (logging-format-interpolation)
app.py:58:4: W1202: Use % formatting in logging functions and pass the % parameters as arguments (logging-format-interpolation)
app.py:60:4: W1202: Use % formatting in logging functions and pass the % parameters as arguments (logging-format-interpolation)
```

I searched the net and found this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619790/pylint-message-logging-format-interpolation#:~:text=Use%20%25%20formatting%20in%20logging%20functions,passing%20the%20parameters%20as%20arguments
```

So , I changed this

```
LOG.info(f"Scaling Payload: \n{payload}")
```

to this

```
LOG.info(f"Scaling Payload: \n %s",payload)
```

But still the pylint shows the same message as above

I am naive.
Please tell me what to do

Comment: Did you find an answer to the problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to remove `f` in your last example:

> So , I changed this
>
> ```
> LOG.info(f"Scaling Payload: \n{payload}")
> ```
>
> to this
>
> ```
> LOG.info(f"Scaling Payload: \n %s",payload)
> ```
>
> But still the pylint shows the same message as above

Solution:

```
LOG.info("Scaling Payload: \n %s", payload)
```

You should remove `f` and it will pass the check.

Tested. Lint passed for me on `pylint 2.6.0` version.