# How to do new-style lazy formatting python logging

Tags: python, logging, pylint, python-logging

This concerns pylint and python logging. The following code doesn't work:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='{message}', style='{')
log.debug('url {}', url)
```

It raises:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 363, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How do I make the logging work with the {} style instead of %s?

I'm using this basicConfig while testing my modules but I can also have a more advanced formatter in my package. The reason I started exploring this is because pylint was complaining when I used f-strings, but also when I was using old formatting with (%s).

Comment: That isn't possible. The style parameter is only for the format that you can set with the `format` parameter, or by using a `Formatter` , but not when calling the log methods.

Comment: I see now, thank you.

Comment: @blue this is possible with python 3.2+. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715402/1595865

Answer (score 2):

The `logging` lazy formatting simply consists of `"%s"` placeholder then, following the string and separated by commas, the values to replace those placeholders.

In this case:

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
log.debug("url %s", url)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `logging-format-style=new` in your `pylintrc`.

Since [pylint 2.2](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.2.html):

> logging-format-style is a new option for the logging checker for usage of str.format() style format strings in calls to loggers.

> It accepts two options: --logging-format-style=old for using % style formatting, which is the assumed default, and --logging-format-style=new for using {} style formatting.

There is also a fstring style, see this very good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027338/2519059