# Delayed python logging and pylint logging-format-interpolation

Tags: python, logging, pylint

AFAIK pylint's logging-format-interpolation tries to nudge me to use "%"-interpolation so it can delay execution to cases where it is strictly necessary, as e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619790/pylint-message-logging-format-interpolation).

However, I am not able to produce an example where this delay actually happens:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def log_identity(s: str) -> str:
    logging.warning('warning %s', s)
    return s

logging.debug('%s', log_identity('c'))  # Expect delay, i.e. no warning c
logging.debug(f"{log_identity('d')}")  # Expect no delay, i.e. warning d
```

However, while the actual debug part never emits a message (as per expectations), the strings get interpolated both times:

```
WARNING:root:warning c
WARNING:root:warning d
```

Short of explicitly using `.isEnabledFor` (cf. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization)), is there a way of preventing evaluation of log messages using "%"-interpolation? If so, how does it look?

Comment: I think your example does not actually test that the string in the logging is evaluated or not. The function ``log_identity`` is executed and your warning logging too. This can't be avoided without using ``isEnabledFor``. But the actual formatting of ``'%s' % result`` is what the pylint's warning is trying to avoid unless required.