# Printing a tuple in Python with user-defined precision

Tags: python

Following [Printing tuple with string formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602/printing-tuple-with-string-formatting-in-python), I'd like to print the following tuple:

```
tup = (0.0039024390243902443, 0.3902439024390244, -0.005853658536585366, -0.5853658536585366)
```

with only 5 digits of precision. How can I achieve this?

(I've tried `print("%.5f" % (tup,))` but I get a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`).

Comment: Tuples don't have precision, floats do. And you're trying to convert a tuple to a float, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround:

```
tup = (0.0039024390243902443, 0.3902439024390244, -
       0.005853658536585366, -0.5853658536585366)

print [float("{0:.5f}".format(v)) for v in tup]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print the floats with custom precision "like a tuple":

```
>>> tup = (0.0039024390243902443, 0.3902439024390244, -0.005853658536585366, -0.5853658536585366)
>>> print('(' + ', '.join(('%.5f' % f) for f in tup) + ')')
(0.00390, 0.39024, -0.00585, -0.58537)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following (list comprehension)

```
['%.5f'% t for t in tup]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class showlikethis(float):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%0.5f" % self

tup = (0.0039024390243902443, 0.3902439024390244, -0.005853658536585366, -0.5853658536585366)
tup = map(showlikethis, tup)
print tup
```

You may like to re-quote your question, tuple dnt have precision.

Comment: o the one who down voted, the mighty intelligent being: a small comment with little explanation would have helped us.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over tuple like this, and than you can print result
for python > 3

```
["{:.5f}".format(i) for i in tup]
```

And for python 2.7

```
['%.5f'% t for t in tup]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Pythonic way to achieve this is with `map()` and `lambda()` function.

```
>>> map(lambda x: "%.5f" % x, tup)
['0.00390', '0.39024', '-0.00585', '-0.58537']
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another workaround using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=5)
print(np.array(tup))
```

which yields the following output:

```
[ 0.0039   0.39024 -0.00585 -0.58537]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a convenient function for python >3.6 to handle everything for you:

```
def tuple_float_to_str(t, precision=4, sep=', '):
    return '({})'.format(sep.join(f'{x:.{precision}f}' for x in t))
```

Usage:

```
>>> print(funcs.tuple_float_to_str((12.3456789, 8), precision=4))
(12.3457, 8.0000)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can work on single item.
Try this:

```
>>> tup = (0.0039024390243902443, 0.3902439024390244, -0.005853658536585366, -0.5853658536585366)
>>> for t in tup:
    print ("%.5f" %(t))


0.00390
0.39024
-0.00585
-0.58537
```