# Taking out space from zip function

Tags: python

I was wondering how I would take out the whitespace in a zip function.

So for example if my code is:

```
for a,b,c, in zip(firstlist,secondlist,thirdlist):
    print(a,b,c)
```

I'm left with a space between a and b as well as between b and c. I was wondering how I would get rid of that.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(str(a)+str(b)+str(c))` instead of `print(a,b,c)`. This will concatenate the values in one string, while now it prints a, b, c as elements of a tuple.

Comment: If OP is asking what you think he is asking then this is not the way to go.

Comment: I think he probably doesn't realise the difference between tuple and string while printing, and I'm providing enough hints for him to find out. Anyway, that's they way I would think of doing it, I'm open to other ideas

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I think you'd be better off taking control for the format you're printing as follows:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["A","B","C"]
list3 = ["1","2","3"]

for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print "%s %s %s" % (a, b, c)
```

The string formatting allows you to control *exactly* how you want the output to look. For example, if you want commas and not spaces you change the code to...

```
for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print "%s%s%s" % (a, b, c)
```

What my code is saying is...

> "Using a string format of `"%s%s%s"` that expects three strings, plug in the values that you'll find in the tuple `(a, b, c)`"

Your original code was printing the string representation of a tuple. When you print a tuple, it happens to print with brackets and commas...

[Printing tuple with string formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602/printing-tuple-with-string-formatting-in-python)

... which is coincidentally similar to the format you wanted.