# Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, for-loop, types, converters

I'm  starting to learn Python
I wrote a code to get a list of numbers from the user and show the even numbers:

```
numbers=list(input("Please enter numbers:"))

def is_even_num():
    enum = []
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            enum.append(n)
    return enum

print(is_even_num())
```

But unfortunately it shows the following error
Can you please tell me what the error means and how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

> But unfortunately it shows the following error Can you please tell me what the error means and how can I fix the error?

You are getting [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) exception at `if n % 2 == 0:` as interpreter is trying to apply [formatting using `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602/printing-tuple-with-string-formatting-in-python). `input()` returns a str object and if you pass it to `list` constructor, it will form a list of characters in your string.

Therefore, `numbers=list(input("Please enter numbers:"))` will be forming a list of `str` objects (For example, if you pass `1 2 3` to your program, it will convert it to a list of str object: `['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3']`).

You need to convert them to `int` using `int` constructor. If you can just change the first line in your program to `numbers=list(map(int, input("Please enter numbers: ").split(" ")))`, it will start working

Try this:

```
numbers=list(map(int, input("Please enter numbers: ").split(" ")))
def is_even_num():

    enum = []
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            enum.append(n)
    return enum
print(is_even_num())
```

Pythonic way of doing the same thing using [list comprehension](http://print([i%20for%20i%20in%20map(int,%20input(%22Please%20enter%20the%20number:%20%22).split(%22%20%22))%20if%20not%20i%20%25%202])):

```
print([i for i in map(int, input("Please enter the number: ").split(" ")) if not i % 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

`numbers=list(input("Please enter numbers:"))` will convert each char to an element in a list, i.e. if you input `1 2 3 4`, each whitespace will also be an element. Try

```
numbers=input("Please enter numbers:").split()
```

This will omit whitespaces.

Also, you're trying to compare a string literal to an integer. In your loop, parse `n` as an integer, i.e.

```
if int(n) % 2 == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
def is_even_num():

    enum = []
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            enum.append(n)
    return enum
print(is_even_num())
```

Input is stored as a string , we need to type cast it into an integer before performing any kind of arithmetic operations on it

Answer (score 0):

numbers is a list of strings, including strings with only spaces

```
['3', ' ', '5', ' ', '8']
```

These spaces you have to remove and then convert the remaining number strings to ints before you use the modulo %

```
numbers = list(input("Please enter numbers:"))

print(numbers)

def is_even_num():
    enum = []
    for n in numbers:
        if n.strip(' '):
            if int(n) % 2 == 0:
                enum.append(int(n))
    return enum

print(is_even_num())
```